# Host an apache web server locally on Ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, web-services, apache-2.2

I want to host an Apache web server and want to upload files on it . 
can someone please give me a broad idea to getting started and basic mechanism behind local Apache server. Related links will be highly appreciated.

PS: I am not an expert Linux user, so please respond on a basic level about Linux commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice guide to get started: http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies